# socket io emit failed callback

Tags: callback, socket.io, emit

Is there any way to know socket io emit failed and success, something like ajax callback methods: onSuccess, onError?
For socket io emit i only find:

> socket.emit('publish', {message:'test message'},function (data) {
>   alert("")})

This callback only be called when the server send an ack response.But it can not apply for this situation:

> At the moment of emit message to server, there is bad network or lost connection, that means server not receive this message, so the client callback function is not called.

What I want is:

> When I call the socket io emit, if it fails, I want to retry 3 times.

Comment: If you want to imitate HTTP behaviour you'd have to write that mechanism yourself, as it's not part of the websocket's job. But it can be done pretty easily with `setTimeout` and a few flags.

Comment: Have you tried using 'error' event callback ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but just in case anyone is still having trouble with this.

```
var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {
    'reconnection': true,
    'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
    'reconnectionDelayMax' : 5000,
    'reconnectionAttempts': 3
});
socket.on('connect_error', function() {
    console.log('Connection failed');
});
socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
    // fired only after the 3 attemps in this example fail
    console.log('Reconnection failed');
});
```

More info here -> https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager-reconnectionAttempts-value